# Establish connection between different tables in a database system

Tags: sql, database, database-design, create-table

I create different tables in a database system .. now I need to make a relationship between them I mean the primary key in one table should be connected to a foreign key in another table.. Should I do that when I create the table itself or it they will be connected together when I insert the data and they they are identical?

For example I do the following when I create two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
  fname    varchar(15),
  minit    varchar(1),
  lname    varchar(15),
  ssn      char(9),
  bdate    date,
  address  varchar(50),
  sex      char,
  salary   decimal(10,2),
  superssn char(9),
  dno      number(4)
);

CREATE TABLE department (
  dname        varchar(25),
  dnumber      number(4),
  mgrssn       char(9), 
  mgrstartdate date
);
```

Here the dno should be connected to the dnumber while the ssn should be connected to the mgrssn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the data doesn't do anything special to the constraints on the tables, how is your db going to know that the values are identical? They might look the same but have different meanings in different places.

If your table declaration includes a foreign key reference to your other table then that's all that there is to it.

If not (and I don't see one in your example) then you should add one in order to maintain referential integrity.

You could add constraints after you've added data, but if any data is not valid (like nulls in your foreign key field) then you won't be able to add the constraint.

Comment: SO you mean when I create the table (when I write the sql statement for creating a new table ) I should specify the primary key and the foreign key, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, that is usually the best practice

Answer (score 0):

Database table relationships are constraints that need to be created. You shouldn't rely on just the data.

> Database constraints are user-defined structures that let you restrict
>   the behaviors of columns.

**PRIMARY KEY Constraint**

> A PRIMARY KEY constraint checks whether a column value will be unique
>   among all rows in a table and disallows null values. Therefore, a
>   PRIMARY KEY has the behaviors of both NOT NULL and UNIQUE constraints.
>   A PRIMARY KEY may span two or more columns. A multiple column PRIMARY
>   KEY is known as a composite or compound key, which can be confusing
>   but essentially the terms only mean that the key spans columns.

**FOREIGN KEY Constraint**

> A FOREIGN KEY constraint restricts the values that are acceptable in a
>   column or group of columns to those values found in a listing of the
>   column or group of columns used to define the primary key. Dependent
>   on the implementation, this may or may not impose a NOT NULL column
>   constraint on all members of the foreign key. If the implementation
>   make the column or set of columns mandatory, then it makes the
>   cardinality of columns in the FOREIGN KEY mandatory, or 1..1 to the
>   PRIMARY KEY. However, the default is that a FOREIGN KEY is 0..1 to the
>   PRIMARY KEY, which means that a row may be inserted in the table with
>   the FOREIGN KEY column. At least, it can be done provided that the
>   constrained column or set of columns are null values.

Here is a [useful link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/08/sql-server-%E2%80%93-2008-creating-primary-key-foreign-key-and-default-constraint/) for creating these constraints with SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Ok good. So yes, when you create a table you add the keys. Sometimes you'll make amendments afterwards, but usually you add keys at the initial design phase.

Comment: I have another question.. why when I insert the following lines in sql command line, it is written that the last line has an error.. Really I can't see that ?

Comment: CREATE TABLE Architecture_Review                               
(
  service_name    varchar(30) not null, 
  A_Ref           varchar(10),
  A_Title    varchar(50)   not null,         
  A_Risk_Rating   varchar(50)   not null,
  A_Root_cause   varchar(50) not null,
  A_Impact    varchar(50) not null,
  A_Likelihood    varchar(50) not null,
  A_Efforts   varchar(50) not null,
  A_Finding      varchar (500) not null, 
  A_Implication   varchar (500) not null, 
  A_Recommendation  varchar(500) not null, 
FOREIGN KEY (service_name) PEFERENCES Services(ser_name));

Comment: and this is Services table that I wrote and it was inserted successfully                                                   CREATE TABLE Services 
(
ser_name        varchar(30)  not null,
ID                  int          not null,
Primary key (ser_name));

Comment: You have not spelled REFERENCES correctly - you have put "PEFERENCES".